# How I can override virtualNic adapter defaultGateway using pyvmomi?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

Here is the code
As I have already created virtual nic on host
I am trying to use updateVirtualNic method configManager.networkSystem

```
    vnic_config = vim.host.VirtualNic.Specification()
    vnic_config.ipRouteSpec = vim.host.VirtualNic.IpRouteSpec()
    vnic_config.ipRouteSpec.ipRouteConfig = vim.host.IpRouteConfig()
    vnic_config.ipRouteSpec.ipRouteConfig.defaultGateway = gateway
    try:
        host_obj.configManager.networkSystem.UpdateVirtualNic('vmk1', vnic_config)
    except Exception as e:
        self.args.rt.comment(e.msg)
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?